# Значение и происхождение слова "бренный"

Tags: этимология, семантика

Слово **бренный**, как вы его понимаете? Уже в пушкинское время оно имело отпечаток ушедшей старины, однако живет слово! В качестве иллюстрации - картина великого художника : "Старый человек, старая лошадь, старый сарай, старый мир"...
[image: Рокуэлл Кент]

Comment: Я не понял, зачем тут правка, но на всяк случай проголосовал "за" - откатить никогда не поздно. Автор правки уверяет, что такой формат ссылок якобы больше не поддерживается. Но я реально не вижу разницы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для меня бренный - это невечный, временный, то, что может быть подвержено тлению.  Иногда использую выражения "бренное тело" . Ассоциация - ничто не вечно под луной.

Comment: Теперь ждем сообщений о происхождении слова, заголовок вопроса обязывает сказать что-нибудь о первоначальном смысле бренности.

Comment: В этимологических словарях (Фасмера и Крылова) происхождение  этого слова тоже связано с глиной.   

 В словаря Даля: БРЕНИЕ ср. церк. распущенная глина, грязь. Бренный, глиняный, взятый от земли, от праху; скудельный; непрочный, слабый, подпадающий разрушению. Бренность ж. непрочность, разрушимость, подчиненность общим законам конечной, земной природы.  


  Так что на этот раз полное единодушие :)

Answer (score 5):

Так как вопрос, - "как **вы** его понимаете?" - то отвечать буду не заглядывая в словарь.

Для меня "бренный" ассоциируется со словом "бремя". Бренный - это несущий бремя, тяготящий. В активный словарный запас слово у меня не входит, но особых проблем с восприятием и порой даже с воспроизведением (правда последнее только в словосочетаниях "бренный мир" и "бренное тело"), тоже нет.

Comment: Вы избрали хорошую тактику, но я "не запрещаю" словарей!))) Прошу дополнять, слово того ст**о**ит...

Comment: В словаре прочитал, что слово бренный получило свое сегодняшнее значение, вероятно, в связи с тем, что всему живому суждено уйти в землю, то есть в глину, в брьнь.

Comment: " Примерно так: Александр [Македонский] умер,
Александра
похоронили, Александр стал прахом,
прах  -  земля, из земли  добывают
глину.
Почему глине, в которую он
обратился, не оказаться в обмазке
пивной бочки?
     Истлевшим Цезарем от стужи
     Заделывают дом снаружи.
     Пред кем весь мир лежал в пыли,
     Торчит затычкою в щели."

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то, слово "брение", насколько я знаю, означает землю, грязь, пыль. Поэтому "бренный" — это тот, кто со временем "уйдет в землю", истлеет.

Answer (score 3):

Требуется подвести некоторые итоги, связанные с **глиной**.

*Брение* - глина, грязь, горшечная земля. *Бренная храмина* - "человеческое тело". *Бреноделатель* - гончар, делающий глиняную посуду. (Церковный словарь 1815, сост. П.Алексеев)

*Скудель* - глина, черепица, сосуд глиняный. *Скудельный* - сделанный из глины. Синонимы (перен.) - *бренный и скудельный* - недолговечный. *Скудельник* - гончар (Словарь Академии Российской 1794). Цитата из Славянской Библии (Иерем. 18,6) :

> еда, якоже скудельник сей, не
> возмогу сотворити вас, доме
> израилевъ? рече господь: се, якоже
> **брение в руку скудельника**, тако вы
> есте, доме израилев, в руку моею

Что касается слова ЗЬДЪ, о котором бесчисленные источники сообщают : это есть *глина*, то я не поленился отыскать превосходный фундаментальный научный труд : "Словарь старославянского языка",  подготовленный Чешской Академией наук в 1966-97, переизданный в С-Петербурге в 2006. В нем собран весь словарный фонд СС языка 9-12 веков из 95 источников. Вот что в нем ответственно пишется :

> ЗЬДЪ, м. или ЗЬДЬ, ж.
>
> 1. **обработанная** глина, сосуд, черепок, testa (лат. *горшок, урна, кирпич, черепок*
>
> 2.стена, постройка, tectum (лат. *крыша, кровля, дом*)

В общем, **изделие**, творение рук человеческих, *то, что сделано*. Скорее всего, слово это не "природное", а обычная церковная калька с греческого и латыни.

Answer (score 2):

Должен признаться, организация данного форума не позволяет многих вещей. Например, вступать в полемику для дополнительных разъяснений.

Поэтому здесь я даю ответ Элен:
 Вы  в данном случае не правы. Фонетический принцип распространяется только на письменность. На говор это никак  не влияет.

***Теперь не по теме. Хочу также выразить благодарность Грумант за чёткую иллюстрацию по поводу фамилии Бодуэна в виде предоставления обложки издания. Я оказался не прав, понадеявшись на опыт историка Ю. Мухина, отыскавшего в архивах написание  этой фамилии как Болдуэн. И тем не менее, я буду наставивать на своём, "ибо это нелепо" (допустим, даже в силу того, что "русский язык будет жить по Стрельцову").  Должен отметить, у меня натура настолько волевая, что я , просто в пику всем нынешним русским филологам, сделаю специальную оговорку , чтобы фамилия автора  русской фонетики писалась всегда только как Болдуэн.  Это будет своеобразная сатисфакция за то, чтобы в теории русского языка сохранилось не вполне адекватное в фонетическом отношении правило: Звукосочетания "жи" и  "ши" пишутся с буквой и.

Хотелось бы пообщаться с Грумант , мне этот человек нравится. Это Вы - http://grumant.33bru.com/   ?
Мой адрес эл. почты strelzovia@mail.ru

Comment: Спасибо, Иван, я Вам уже ответил по э/почте. А ссылка не моя, хотя совпадение интересное)))